# How do I install Enlightenment on RetroPie For PiZero?

Tags: pi-zero, retropie, gui

I have installed Retropie and used it's built in LXDE desktop environment on a Pi Zero. From a search on the internet some has found Enlightenment quite zippy. I would like to try this instead of LXDE as a Retropie port option for desktop. Is this possible, if so I am willing to do the work, just may need some pointers to find information for config file setup and repositories etc.

Thankyou for taking the time to read.

Comment: Your question title is confusing, consider changing it to match the actual question. E.g. "How do I install Enlightenment on Retropie?"

Comment: sorry my retropie installation is on a PiZero i have changed the title to make this clearer